# Can we say Dirac delta function is zero almost surely?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

It is known that $\delta(x) = \infty $ if $x = 0$ and $=0$ if $x\ne 0 $ and we also know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx=1$.  However, if we consider a Lebesgue integration, $\delta(x)$ is zero almost surely so that we can get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)d\mu(x)=0$.

Why I get a contradiction here?

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is that $\delta$ is not a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, even though some throw it around as if it were.

Comment: No, it is not a function, it is a distribution or measure depending on your viewpoint. If you are looking from a measure perspective, $\delta(A) = 1_A(0)$.

Comment: The Dirac delta function is sometimes problematic when we think of it as a function in the classical sense.  If you are going to treat it right it is a "distribution" or "linear functional."  But, plenty of people who care about the "right answer" more than the theory or mathematical rigor, can be a little bit fast and loose with the definitions, and treat it as a function.

Comment: Many Many thanks for your helpful and professional explanation MPW,copper.hat, Doug M    !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that is a bad "definition" of the "Dirac function"!  The "Dirac function" is not a function at all, it is a "distribution" or "generalized function", a **functional** that assigns a number to every function.  Specifically, the "Dirac function" assigns the number f(0) to every function, f.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer!